# PHPUnit only runs first file in directory

Tags: phpunit

In a directory I have two files

oneTest.php

```
<?php

class oneTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testSomethingOne()
    {
        echo 'ONE TEST';
        $this->assertEquals(1, 1);
    }

}
```

twoTest.php

```
<?php

class twoTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testSomethingTwo()
    {
        echo 'TWO TEST';
        $this->assertEquals(2, 2);
    }

}
```

From within the directory I can run both tests fine

```
phpunit oneTest.php
phpunit twoTest.php
```

And I get the expected output on both.

If I try and run all tests with

```
phpunit *
```

It only runs the first test.

I'm running phpunit 3.6.12 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply a limitation of phpunit, it is not programmed to support multiple files on the command line. You can, however, [pass a directory name to phpunit](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/organizing-tests.html). If you want to run the tests in the current directory, use

```
phpunit .
```

Edit: alternatively, you can specify a testsuite in a [XML configuration file](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html).